# pandas: IndexError while trying to iterate through rows in a DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am converting a script from Matlab to Python that deals with signal processing. The function I am currently working on looks at a universal set of data to find the time stamps where frequency and step responses occur. Basically if there is a chunk of time missing, that means an input from the machine occurred, so I need to parse that data from a different csv file. Here is the basic layout of the DataFrame:

```
   Time Stamp (sec)  PCmd (deg)  PPos (deg)  ...   Volts  Flags  Counter
0         96.676872     -0.0161     -0.1290  ...  98.230      0       20
1         96.683545      0.0000     -0.0645  ...  58.421      0       43
2         96.690234      0.0000      0.0000  ...  98.747      0       49
3         96.696512      0.0000     -0.0645  ...  72.380      0       73
4         96.703550      0.0000     -0.0645  ...  66.176      0       94
```

It has 6065 rows and 12 columns.

The purpose of this function is to create a nested list of sorts where the gaps in between events are stored as elements in the list. Each element would be a section of the overall DataFrame. That is my 'outmat' list. 'zeromat' is the DataFrame. 'zbreaks' is a list that stores the index values of where responses/discontinuities occur.

My error is occurring in the first if statement where I am compared two consecutive values to see if the difference in time is outside of the acceptable range.

```
# set constants
sampledis=5
dt = 1/128

# set DataFrame variable
zeromat = df1

# set variables for row & col length
zr = zeromat.shape[0]
zc = zeromat.shape[1]

#initialize lists 
zbreaks = []
outmat = []

# Find the discontinuities
for m in range(zr+2):
    # Line where IndexError is occurring 
    if (int(zeromat.iloc[m+1,0])-int(zeromat.iloc[m,0])) > (dt*sampledis):
            zbreaks.append(m)

# Parse zeromat into cell array
if len(zbreaks) != 0:
    outmat.append(zeromat.iloc[:zbreaks[0],])
```

The error that displays is "IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds"

Let me know if any more information is needed, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `df` only has a length of `zr` (5 in your example) so you can index it up to `zr-1` (4) with `iloc`. Yet with your loop you're trying to index it up to `zr+2` (7), which is out of bounds. Do you perhaps mean `for m in range(zr - 2)`

Comment: @ALollz you are correct, I need to subtract from the range instead of add. Thanks for your help!